# Using Ajax to Make Rails Website Faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i'm creating a website and i'm thinking of ways to make it load as fast as possible. My website, as it happens with most, has a layout that is the same for every page. For instance, the header, the external divs and so on are defined once in a layout and used likewise for every page that loads. The menu is always on the leftest div and never changes, and so on.

So, think of 5 areas. Top, left, center, right and footer. In my case, only the center has to change, depending on the page that i want to load. Therefore, i was thinking that using Ajax to do that would make loading way faster, since all other elements would already be loaded, right ?

So, i would like to ask whether there is a good resource or online tutorial that discusses this matter, as i would like to take a close look.

Thank you for reading that :)

Comment: 1 image in the content would probably render this optimization useless. The amount of data you are saving from not loading the header/foot is probably not much considering most of it should be cached. I'd look at the standard ways of optimizing the page first.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808601/how-to-optimise-site-load-times-in-ruby

Comment: Beware, ajax may drift towards clumsy apps if you don't uphold web basics: one page = one url. Why don't you cache the parts of your app you use again and again?

Comment: why is that ? I don't really get it.

Comment: @apneadiving, i will use one page = one url anyway. It's just an optimization of loading that page inside the content and not reloading everything. However, i think that caching may be a very good option indeed.

Comment: A reason why i was leaning towards ajax is that i have a tab like environment that works with javascript and preloads everything on every tab. Maybe it would be better to change that and use caching as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @apneadiving's comment on caching the parts of the app, you'd use the fragment caching to handle that. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html

You can load contents of the "main" part of your page using the approach here (using jQuery)
[Replace HTML page with contents retrieved via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483745/replace-html-page-with-contents-retrieved-via-ajax)

Unless you know that your site's performance is unacceptable and that ajax will fix an issue you should probably avoid complicating things by using ajax.  Remember `premature optimization is the root of all evil` :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to avoid RJS because it's server-side javascript.

Use regular Ajax calls with the JS framework you like. A good asset here: http://peepcode.com/products/jquery-ajax